# Is there a way to get Arch to run fully after deleting the home partition?

Tags: arch-linux, home

I tried dual booting Kali Linux on an existing Arch Linux and I may have formatted the home partition for Arch in the process. So I was wondering is there any way at all that I can get Arch to run again fully without installing it all over again?

Comment: Please update question with details of any errors being shown.

Comment: Well, there are no errors as such. Just that you can only log in as root and can't do anything else after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home partition is not required for system to be operational. However, many programs store configuration files in home directory. This might be the problem you are encountering. In this case, the simplest solution would be to use backup(which each user should have). If you don't have backup for some reason, you can resort to reconstructing crucial files(it will require some googling), or you can reinstall your programs, hoping that they will put some default configuration by themselves, so you can edit it later.

Comment: Sorry if this question sounds corny,am a newbie at this, the backups you're talking about, are they automatically created because am sure I never created any?

Comment: I was referring to fact, that it is good practice to make backups on regular basis. If you are using Arch, I would expect you to be somewhat more advanced user(and hence create backups). However, if you did not keep backups for some reason, system won't keep them automatically for you - just go on, repair your system, and after that google for some ways of creating backup - and make sure you have it on separate media. This way, next time such situation happens - you can avoid many problems.

Comment: Hey, I got it to work. It was actually pretty easy. All I had to do was create a new user to help get to the log in shell without root. Then I had to create a new .xinit file, which is of course one line, and voila I startx'ed to my kde.